# How to use date filter in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-query

I am using the client object of elasticsearch.

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host:"https://********",
    log: 'trace',
});


"hits": [
        {
            "_index": "abc",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "39KueHEBnbKK-Fpwq9wG",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "videoId": "EV-IOHABXh-qOCdiWVbW",
               "createddate": "2020-04-14 18:04:05"


            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "abc",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "29KueHEBnbKK-Fpwq9wG",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "videoId": "zV-IOHABXh-qOCdiWVbW",
                 "createddate": "2020-03-14 18:04:05",


            }
        }
    ]
```

I am trying to filter based on **createddate**. This is my query which I am trying to filter out the data but not working. Please help me.

**Note**: I need to filter data between two dates.

```
{
   "query": {
    "bool": {
        "filter": [
            {

                "range": {
                    "createddate": {
                        "gte": "2020-04-11 00:00:00",
                        "lte": "2020-04-16 23:59:59"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Field name in index and query is different .It is createdDate in index and createddate in query. Note "d" in date. Is it typo in question or also in actual query

Comment: My bad @jaspreetchahal. Thanks for the it. Actually I want to filter between two dates that are requested by the frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "createddate": {
        "type": "date",
        "format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Indexed two documents**

```
{
    "videoId": "EV-IOHABXh-qOCdiWVbW",
    "createddate":"2020-04-14 18:04:05"
 }

 {
 "videoId": "zV-IOHABXh-qOCdiWVbW",
 "createddate": "2020-03-14 18:04:05"
 }
```

**Same Search Query which you provided:**

```
{
   "query": {
    "bool": {
        "filter": [
            {

                "range": {
                    "createddate": {
                        "gte": "2020-04-11 00:00:00",
                        "lte": "2020-04-16 23:59:59"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

**Result:**

```
"hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.0,
            "_source": {
               "videoId": "EV-IOHABXh-qOCdiWVbW",
               "createddate": "2020-04-14 18:04:05"
            }
         }
      ]
```

The search query filters the data between the two dates, and gives out the expected result.

Comment: @Rahul Saini glad could be of help :)